# Get number of elements in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to obtain number of elements in Firebase Realtime DB.

I can get number of childs but not number of elements.

For example:

https://i.hizliresim.com/Lb46ao.png

As you see number of childs 3, my code returns 3 but I want to count all elements not childs.

```
root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        totalSize = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); //It gives 3, 
        //not number of elements. I want to obtain number of elements. Number of elements 1204 for now. 
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently counting the number of properties under each child, so that gives 3: `msg`, `name`, `time`.

To count the number of children, you'll want to use a `ValueEventListener`:

```
root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        totalSize = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```